# PHP datetime comparing days

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm comparing dates with this code:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24 12:10:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26 14:00:30");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

If I echo this: `echo $interval->m." months and".$interval->d." days.";` I get the output `3 months and 2 days.`. Now, I want to echo the difference between the dates but include the amount of months in the day count, so a difference of 1 month (with 30 days in it) and 5 days would be 35 days, not 1 month and 5 days. How do I do this?

I'm using PHP version 5.3+.

Comment: You can use the [format function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: @Kacey no, there are better ways

Comment: @STTLCU Thanks. I didn't really think about what he wanted before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
$interval->days;
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days

```
echo "There are ".$interval->days." days between the two dates.";
```

Comment: Well...that was easier then expected! Accepting in 9 minutes (damn timer..).

Comment: Quick offtopic: how do I make a datetime object from the current date and time?

Answer (score 1):

Your `$interval` variable is of type [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Therefore, `$interval->days` should yeld the desired output.